# How to download a file from the webview in os x and save it to a specific location

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, webview

I have looked everywhere and have not found exactly what I am looking for, so here is my question:

I have a basic app I am playing around with. I have created a webview and would like to be able to download a file from the website that loads in the webview and save the file to say the Downloads folder on the local machine. The site loads fine inside the webview, now how do I download a file, say an .xml file from the site and save it to the Downloads folder on the local machine?

This is what I have so far:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];//<-- example site
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];



}
```

I would like to be able to download a file (possible using a delegate) then  save it to a location on the local computer. I am pretty new to this so I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been resolved. I added the following code to make it work:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]; // <-- example website
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    self.webView.policyDelegate = self;
    [self.webView setDownloadDelegate:self];
    [[self.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];

}

- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForMIMEType:(NSString *)type
                                                    request:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                                    frame:(WebFrame *)frame
                                            decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
{
    if([type isEqualToString:@"application/octet-stream"]) //this is the type I was looking for
    {
        //figure out how to save file here

        [listener download];
        NSURLDownload *downLoad = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        if(downLoad)
        {
            [self download:downLoad decideDestinationWithSuggestedFilename:@"filename.ext"];
            NSLog(@"File Downloaded Succesfully");
            //[webView close];
            [self.window close];

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"The download failed");
        }



    }
    //just ignore all other types; the default behaviour will be used
}

-(void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download decideDestinationWithSuggestedFilename:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSString *destinationFileName;
    NSString *homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory();

    destinationFileName = [[homeDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    [download setDestination:destinationFileName allowOverwrite:NO]; //file is being saved to the Documents folder on the local machine
}
```

Hope this will be helpful to someone else.

Comment: I moved the answer from the question to the answer. It's great that you solved the problem, but it's best to put the answer in the answers, not as an edit to the question!

Comment: @EdCottrell thanks for this. How do I just use the filename of the item being downloaded rather than name it myself?

Comment: @JimBak I have no idea. This is not my answer; I simply edited it as part of some site cleanup. To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.