# OS X webview get actual filename string

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview

I've successfully implemented NSURLDownload in a webview thanks to the link below. In the code, I have to specify a filename. I would rather use the filename of the file being downloaded. How do I get that filename?

[How to download a file from the webview in os x and save it to a specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287129/how-to-download-a-file-from-the-webview-in-os-x-and-save-it-to-a-specific-locati/26385689?noredirect=1#comment55128787_26385689)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it out of the request parameter or pass it in separately from the calling code.

Comment: I was hoping there was a simple thing I could call to get this. I can't even use the code below because some downloads url's don't end with the filename. NSString *filename = [[[request URL] absoluteString] lastPathComponent];

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [download:decideDestinationWithSuggestedFilename:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLDownloadDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLDownloadDelegate/download:decideDestinationWithSuggestedFilename:) method from the [NSURLDownloadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLDownloadDelegate_Protocol/) delegate.

Something like this:

```
// somewhere in your code
myWebView.downloadDelegate = self;

- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download decideDestinationWithSuggestedFilename:(NSString *)filename {


    NSString *destinationFilename = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop"]
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    [download setDestination:destinationFilename allowOverwrite:YES];

}
```